# How to Install Vim Plugins in a Windows Environment

Tags: windows, vim, vim-plugin

I am just getting started with Vim and setting up the environment with some of the plugins recommended by http://vimawesome.com/. I downloaded and placed plug.vim in `C:\Program Files\Vim\vim74\autoload`
and in `C:\Program Files\Vim\vimfiles\plugin` I put the git master branch `nerdtree-master` and renamed it to `nerdtree`. In the `_vimrc` file, which is otherwise working, I put

```
Plug 'scroloose/nerdtree
```

and

```
Plug 'nerdtree
```

Neither of these commands worked. And I receive this error:

```
Error detected while processing C:\Program Files\Vim\_vimrc:

line    7:

E492: Not an editor command: Plug 'nerdtree'

Error detected while processing
C:\Program Files\Vim\vim74\plugin\nerdtree\lib\nerdtree\path.vim:
```

Comment: Your plugin manager (what provides the `Plug` command) isn't properly installed. What steps / instructions did you follow? Is there something (above that) in your `.vimrc` that invokes `autoload/plug.vim`? Also, better install your user configuration into `$HOME/_vimrc` / `$HOME/vimfiles`, not into the system location.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally figured out that I had forgot to wrap the line `Plug 'nerdtree'` with

```
call plug#begin('~/.vim/plugged')
Plug 'nerdtree'
call plug#end()
```

Although `.vim` is a Linux path, Vim or Vim-Plug was able to recognize the path. I then received an error that Git must be installed. I already had Git installed, so I simply added `C:\Program Files\Git\bin` to the system environment variable `%PATH%`. After restarting Vim I typed

```
:PlugInstall
```

in the Vim editor.

The vim-plug plugin manager got to work and printed:

```
- Finishing ... Done!
x nerdtree:
    Cloning into 'C:\Users\labbedz7\.vim\plugged\nerdtree'...
    remote: Invalid username or password.
    fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://git::@github.com/vim-scripts/nerdtree.git/'
```

Now, Git did not "authenticate" because the string in `Plug 'String'` refers to the GitHub URL path: `http://github.com/String`. By changing to the actual path: `scrooloose/nerdtree` I was able to run `:PlugInstall` again.

```
call plug#begin('~/.vim/plugged')
Plug 'scrooloose/nerdtree'
call plug#end()
```

This resulted in:

```
Updated. Elapsed time: 5.706874 sec.
[=]

- Finishing ... Done!
- nerdtree: Checking connectivity... done
```

I then added these lines to _vimrc:

```
autocmd StdinReadPre * let s:std_in=1
autocmd VimEnter * if argc() == 0 && !exists("s:std_in") | NERDTree | endif
```

Nerdtree is now running! It starts in Windows\System32 and is a bit slow to load, but it is running.